# Running exe based program on thin client environment (Performance?)

Tags: thin-client

We are evaluating hospital automation softwares for a new hospital. In this hospital we plan to use thin clients on VDA OS. Most of the alternatives that we evaluate are web based. One of the alternative software is a good candidate for us thinking the functions of the software, price and company's support. However this application is designed in client-server architecture. 
I am not familiar to VDI. I haven't used it yet. We just plan to use it for the hospital for the first time. I am not sure using client-server architecture is proper for thin clients thinking the performance of the system. 
The number  of users is important in this concept. We think that around 500+ users will exists. In VDI client (which is in reality stored in the server)  every user  will work as if he is working in its own pc. But in reality  will connect to the server. Using an exe based program in this hardware architecture frightens me . The company says that using exe based program in this hardware architecture will not be a problem. But they don't have a reference working in VDA environment. 
I need help in evaluating these hospital automation software from an expert :) 
Thank you